# Aplicativo de Backup - Online via OneDrive ou Local?

Tags: c#, onedrive

> Apesar dessa pergunta ser meio de opinião pessoal, porém pode ajudar a
>   diversas outras pessoas se colocarmos os pontos positivos e negativos
>   de cada tecnologia.

Tenho um servidor no USA, com link de 1 Gbt/s Full Duplex, hoje não consumo nem 2% dessa banda.
Preciso fazer um aplicativo para backup de fotos nesse servidor. Hoje com quase 5 milhões de fotos e 300GB.
Em média 1000 fotos de 400kb todos os dias. Armazeno essas fotos fisicamente e os nomes delas estão no MS SQL.

Qual o melhor:

**Fazer um aplicativo que armazenará na minha conta OneDrive (1tb) ou localmente na minha empresa?**

Tentei inicialmente criar um mapeamento de unidade do Onedrive e assim faria via Robocopy (aplicativo de comando que faz cópia em massa) para essa unidade. Porém o Windows 2008 R2 não me possibilita esse recurso.

**Vantagens do OneDrive** (creio que será mais rápido do que fazer o download o upload das fotos do que local)

**Desvantagem:** O Software ficará mais complexo visto que provavelmente precisarei do SDK do OneDrive.

Aceito sugestões e pontos que devo considerar nesse tipo de aplicativo.
Como fazer o download de arquivo por arquivo ou de um único arquivo ZIP.

Comment: Provavelmente backup no OneDrive é mais seguro. Se este serviço disponibiliza alguma API ou algo do tipo, para integração com outras aplicações, acredito que seja melhor opção.

Comment: parece que tem mesmo. https://dev.onedrive.com/

Comment: Existe sim uma api e até alguns codigos prontos para o sdk do onedrive, seria mais complexo do que um simples programa de download, mas tem a vantagem de ser nuvem e em teoria lá funciona como se fosse rede, faço download do onedrive a 20mb/s